# How do I "CMake'ify" my inclusion of threads headers?

Tags: c, multithreading, cmake, pthreads

In a source file of mine, I have:

```
#ifdef __unix__
#include <pthread.h>
#else
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <processthreadsapi.h>
#endif // _WIN32
#endif // __unix__
```

(Yes, this is not the greatest piece of code but it's bound by restrictions of another library I'm interacting with.)

Now, CMake is the mechanism which gets me hooked up with the library to link against; so - I want to use the exact same logic as CMake in decide whether to use WIndows threads or pthreads. Or - have CMake take this decision for me.

How should I do that?

I want to have CMake decide these things for me

Comment: Another option to consider would be C++11 threads, if they're appropriate for your needs. If your compilers on both sides are new enough and there aren't other reasons you can't use them, it would be a lot more portable and would simplify your CMake configuration as well.

Comment: @George: Unfortunately, I need this to interact with a C library that itself uses threads, and I'm bound by its restrictions. I guess I'll just reclassify this question as C.

Answer (score 0):

My current idea is to do the following in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
if(DEFINED CMAKE_USE_PTHREADS_INIT)
        target_compile_definitions(cuda-api-wrappers PUBLIC "CUDA_API_WRAPPERS_USE_PTHREADS");
else if(DEFINED CMAKE_USE_WIN32_THREADS_INIT)
        target_compile_definitions(cuda-api-wrappers PUBLIC "CUDA_API_WRAPPERS_USE_WIN32_THREADS");
endif()
endif()
```

then in the C++ file write:

```
#ifdef CUDA_API_WRAPPERS_USE_PTHREADS
#include <pthread.h>
#else
#ifdef CUDA_API_WRAPPERS_USE_WIN32_THREADS
#include <processthreadsapi.h>
#endif
#endif
```

but I wonder if that's the right approach.

Comment: @ZuodianHu: I was hoping CMake has some more tricks for this up its sleeve.

Comment: The only other thing off the top of my head is to use `configure_file`, which is more or less preprocessing using CMake variables.

Comment: @ZuodianHu: Yeah, that is a good idea - but more so if you have multiple configuration settings and not just this one. Still, maybe it's already worth it.